# I am not able to store my token in the cookie with setCookie

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cookies, next.js, next-auth

In the part of authenticating my site with nextAuth and nookies, when I store my token in the cookie it does not store it. ps: The api returns me a token and a refresh, when I store the refresh it works normally but when I store the token it doesn't store it at all.

This is my code:

```
const { token, refresh } = response.data;

setCookie(null, '@token', token, {
  maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1, // expirar em 1 mes
  path: '/'
});

api.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
```

What I hope is to store the token in the cookie to do the authentication part of the project with nookies

Comment: Why first parameter to setCookie is null? I would assume that suppose to be a cookie name and second paramter would be a cookie value..from where are you implementing this setCookie method? is it from react-cookie package?

Comment: I solved the problem, the token size exceeded the limit of 4096 bytes which is the maximum a cookie can store. I Reduced the token size and it worked perfectly. But tks anyway

Answer (score 0):

if you are using 'cookies' you need request or response object to set cookies in the server component.

In Next JS 13, you can use their own [cookies function](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies) to set/get cookies as below:

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

cookies().set({
      name: 'nameOfCookie',
      value: 'valueOfCookie,
      httpOnly: true, //optional
      maxAge: timeOut, //optional
  });
```

you can read more about it here: [Set cookies in next js server components](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#cookiessetname-value-options)